# Create user automatically with Sync Gateway and OIDC Implicit Flow

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-sync-gateway

I’m setting up Couchbase Lite on android with Sync Gateway 2.1 and Couchbase Server 6.0.

I've implemented authentication with Google Sign-in by using the OpenID Connect Implicit flow and I'm able to get the session cookie for authentication.

Now I need authorization to use the "requireUser()" function in the SGW config file's javascript, but **I can't get SGW to create the User for me**.

From what I read in the docs, setting `"register":true` in the config file should make SGW automatically create the user when it doesn't exist, but I keep getting an `Unauthorized` response when sending a request to `/_session` with as body `{ "name": "new_user_name" }`.

What am I missing to be able to create the user with SGW automatically? I have setup Implicit Flow auth to avoid having to manage my own web app for authorization, so I would like to avoid having to use the Admin rest API for user creation.

Here's my SGW config file:

```
{
"log": ["*"],
"adminInterface": ":4985",
"databases": {
    "lucidity": {
        "server": "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8091",
        "bucket": "bucketname",
        "username": "syncgateway",
        "password": "***********",
        "num_index_replicas": 0,
        "enable_shared_bucket_access": true,
        "import_docs": "continuous",
        "oidc": {
            "providers": {
                "GoogleAuthFlow": {
                    "issuer":"https://accounts.google.com",
                    "client_id":"xxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com ",
                    "validation_key":" xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                    "callback_url": "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:4984/bucketname/_oidc_callback",
                    "register":true
                }
            }
        },
        "users": { "GUEST": { "disabled": false, "admin_channels": ["*"] } },
        "sync": `function (doc, oldDoc) {
        }`
    }
}
```

**EDIT**:
Here's the log for my request:

```
POST http://xx.xx.xx.xx:4984/bucketname/_session
    Content-Type: application/json
    Content-Length: 2
    Authorization: [MY_ID_TOKEN_HERE]
    Body: { }
```

And the response is

```
{
      "authentication_handlers" : [ "default", "cookie" ],
      "ok" : true,
      "userCtx" : {
        "channels" : {
          "!" : 1,
          "*" : 1
        },
        "name" : null
      }
    }
```

with the following Set-Cookie header:

```
Set-Cookie: SyncGatewaySession=xxxx; Path=/bucketname; Expires=Fri, 18 Jan 2019 08:50:36 GMT
```

Comment: What does your request to session look like (headers and such) ?

Comment: Please see my post edit for the request and response that I make to the /_session endpoint

Comment: I might be mistaken but I don't think you can choose the user name with automatic creation.  The request and response you showed indicate that the session create succeeded, and you should use the cookie you receive in the replicator.